# Swap pairs of bytes in a hex bytearray in python

Tags: python, arrays

Apologies if this has been asked before, I couldn't find what I needed to do in my googling.
I have converted a hex string to a bytearray in python, and I want to swap the pairs of bytes round. E.g. 0e d8 AB CD should read d8 0e CD AB. I have tried using byteswap but it doesn't seem to work.
Here is the code with which I get the bytearray.

```
#forward RPM         
    if dirVar.get() == ("Forwards"):
        hexRpm =(hex(RPM.get()))
        forwardRpmFinal = bytearray.fromhex((padhexa(hexRpm)))
```

`padhexa` is just a function I'm using to pad the front of the hex bytes with zeros so that the `bytearray` doesn't throw an error when it encounters a single letter or number.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure there are gonna be only 4 numbers in the byte array? Or you want to swap every pair in sequence?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to swap every pair in the sequence as I'm eventually going to have multiple arrays of varying lengths and I want to do the same to all of them.

Comment: Is what you want to achieve a endianness conversion?

Comment: yes, sorry should've been more specific @zanseb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that what you want to achieve is a endiannes conversion between 2 systems I would suggest you look into the struct package https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html.

A little example would be:

```
>>> import struct
>>> var = struct.pack('<h', 5)
>>> var
>>> var = struct.pack('>h', 5)
>>> var
```

For your data the example would be:

```
>>> var = struct.pack('<HH', int("d80e", 16), int("cdab", 16))
>>> var
>>> var = struct.pack('>HH', int("d80e", 16), int("cdab", 16))
>>> var
```

Hope this helps.